# Remove menu bar from IE8 or just disable copy and paste

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

How do I remove the menu bar from IE 8 for the student account? Or even just the Edit menu, or just eliminate the ability to copy and paste?

I'm using Windows Steady State to configure student accounts on computers using XP and need to block the ability to download (or copy) things from the Internet.

I have File Download disabled in Internet Options and turned off right-click with Win Steady State.

However, students could still click and drag to select things and then use the Edit menu to copy and paste.

In the student account the menu bar option is checked and greyed out, even when right-click options are granted, when Computer Administrator rights are granted via control panel. The Admin account has the Menu Bar active.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove pretty much anything from the menu bar using the steps outlined [here](http://jalaj.net/2007/01/01/tweaking-registry-for-internet-explorer/). It also gives you the options for disabling things in the Internet Options dialog as well as disabling buttons on the toolbar (so cut, copy and paste buttons, even if added, will be disabled).